# How could an alien mega structure such as a Dyson Sphere be detected?

Tags: astrophysics

A friend of mine was telling me that if there is an alien structure out there, we could detect it by the energy it would be producing or sending out. Im aware of hubble’s mission (RIP) and how we could make calculations base on transit, but never heard of such a thing... is it true? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A Dyson sphere would be warm, and so it would probably have a spectrum unlike a natural body of that temperature since it would emit infrared but not visible light (unless it has holes in it).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of lack of previous research effort.

Comment: I have put effort into it... why and how do you say that? Because you get it everyone else must get it? And if they ask it means they haven't spent time researching it?

Comment: Are you asking about an actual shell-like megastructure, or do you mean the orbital-cloud-like construction?

Comment: This sphere is nonsense based on silly assumptions. A starry sky is a beautiful thing. No way *advanced* creatures would trade it for an iron prison.

Comment: @safesphere Dyson sphere's are prisons?

Comment: This is kinda the inverse question as [this much earlier question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69649/25301)

Comment: @KyleKanos "*Dyson sphere's are prisons?*" - Yes, yes, indeed they are. In so many respects. Maximum security too. Freedom is to cook a freshly caught fish  on a camp fire staring at the night sky, not to senselessly march in the utopian steel shell on greedy orders of the self appointed elite calling itself "the civilization".

Answer (score 1):

Freeman Dyson originally suggested the structure that now bears his name ([he prefers Stapledon sphere](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Dyson_sphere)) in [a 1960 paper in Science](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/131/3414/1667) because it (1) may be a likely end-state of civilisations using their local resources, and (2) it would be detectable from infrared emissions.

> If the foregoing argument is accepted, then the search for
>   extraterrestrial intelligent beings should not be confined to the
>   neighborhood of visible stars. The most likely habitat for such beings
>   would be a dark object, having a size comparable with the Earth's
>   orbit, and a surface temperature of 200 deg. to 300 deg. K. Such a
>   dark object would be radiating as copiously as the star which is
>   hidden inside it, but the radiation would be in the far infrared,
>   around 10 microns wavelength.

A sphere of radius $R$ that receives the luminosity $L$ of the star will radiate like a blackbody with temperature $$T=\left[\frac{L}{4\pi R^2 \sigma}\right ]^{1/4}.$$ The "standard" assumptions are like in Dyson's paper that it is about 1 AU and at "room temperature". [From an energy collecting efficiency perspective this is likely not optimal](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009457659500009O), and one might have to look for other temperature objects. They still would look like IR point sources, possibly with a bit of normal starlight mixed in if there are small gaps between the orbiting collector.

[Looking for transiting artificial objects is a different issue](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0503580); here the light curve would look odd but the spectrum is unchanged.

[People have done searches for Dyson sphere-like sources](https://home.fnal.gov/~carrigan/infrared_astronomy/Other_searches.htm), with so far no luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... so if a Dyson Sphere is located at about 1,400 LY away... could we still detect its infrared emission? Do we have the technology to analyze such a thing? Thanks again!

Comment: I think so. The IRAS surveys looked that far, I think.